# Sort divs (added dynamically) by classname

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson, deferred

I have been struggling to find a way in which I could sort Divs after being displayed .So far, I have used `prepend()` and `append()` and I have managed to show at first the players that are streaming, but the next divs are random. I want to be able to show who's online, who's not and who has closed the account in order.

I have already tried deferred method: `$.when(makeDivs()).then(sortDivs());`

but it's not working properly, any idea how I can fix this?

My codepen: http://codepen.io/diegomdzr/pen/vKWGbd

Comment: streamers = streamers.sort(); - is it wrong?

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)._

Comment: @AleshaOleg it works for sorting the array beforehand. But I want to sort the divs by classname just after they are added into the page.

Comment: @DiegoM Why first sort them after they have loaded?

Comment: @Jacques Marais I attempt to do it the other way around: Sort them and then display them in order.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reputation to comment yet. But from my understanding, you want to make the classNames of divs in alphabetical order after they have been applied to the document?

```
function reOrder() {

var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var cn = []; //ClassNames of each div.
for (var i = 0; i < div.length; i++) {
    cn.push(div[i].className);
}
cn = cn.sort(); //sort the array in alphabetical order.

var oDiv = [];
for (var i = 0; i < cn.length; i++) {
    //for each array item in cn, find where it's element is, remove the element, continue.
    for (var ii = 0; ii < div.length; ii++) {
        if (div[ii].className == cn[i]) {
            oDiv.push(div[ii]);
            var newDiv = [];
            for (var iii = 0; iii < div.length; iii++) {
                //Remove the element from the array.
                if (div[iii] != div[ii]) {
                    newDiv.push(div[iii]);
                }
            }
            div = newDiv;

        }
    }
}


return oDiv;
};

reOrder();
```

This will return an array of the elements, but sorted. You can then replace all of the elements of the document with these sorted elements.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting is expensive, should be avoided if possible, and isn't a particularly good solution here.

It's way simpler to create a container (div) for each of your streamer categories, (online|offlie|nonExistent) then simply append HTML, as it is generated, to the appropriate container.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var streamers = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas", "comster404", "brunofin", "HorussTV"];
    var link = "https://twitch.com/";

    // Create/append containers here (or hard-code them in HTML) ... in correct order of presentation within #streamers.
    var $onlineStreamers = $("<div/>").appendTo($('#streamers'));
    var $offlineStreamers = $("<div/>").appendTo($('#streamers'));
    var $nonExistantStreamers = $("<div/>").appendTo($('#streamers'));

    streamers.forEach(function getStatus(element) {
        $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/" + element + "?callback=?", function(json) {
            var img = json.logo || "http://res.cloudinary.com/djnwhbm1z/image/upload/v1468187598/unknown_i7m43p.png";
            $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + element + "?callback=?", function(json) {
                // Append HTML to the appropriate container
                if(json.stream) {
                    $onlineStreamers.append('<div class="online"><a href="' + link + element + '" target="_blank"><h4>' + element + '</h4><img src="' + img + '" class="profPic"><div class="content text-center"><span><b>Game:</b></br>' + json.stream.game + ' </br><b>Status: </b>' + json.stream.channel.status + '</span></div></a></div>');
                } else if(json.status == 422) {
                    $nonExistantStreamers.append('<div class="nonExistant"><a href="#"><h4>' + element + '</h4><img src="' + img + '" class="profPic"><div class="content text-center"><span>Account Closed</span></div></a></div>');
                } else {
                    $offlineStreamers.append('<div class="offline"><a href="' + link + element + '" target="_blank"><h4>' + element + '</h4><img src="' + img + '" class="profPic"><div class="content text-center"><span>Offline</span></div></a></div>');
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Notes:

- No sorting required unless the entries need to be sorted *within* each category.
- You can probably purge `class="online"` etc from the appended HTML, unless those classes are used elsewhere.